# Using cookies in .Net 6 Web API

Tags: c#, .net, api, cookies

I find the documentation for .Net is lacking on this topic.

I'm writing a API in C# using .NET 6 framework and I want to store some structured information with the user in a cookie. I read through this guide:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/http-cookies
but the guide is for ASP.NET 4.x and the methods mentioned in the guide does not exist in my enviroment.

After some googling I came across this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.cookies?view=netframework-4.8#system-web-httpresponse-cookies

Which I have seen some people use, however this is also an older framework version and does not seem to work in .NET 6 as there is no such thing as a `HttpCookie` class. But I think using the `Response` attribute of the controller is the way to go. I managed to add a simple cookie using

`Response.Cookies.Append("hello", "world");`

But I find very little information about this `append` method, and it seems to be best for relativley small unstructured data.

In the [docs for ASP.NET 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.cookiebuilder?view=aspnetcore-6.0) I find some refrence to a `CookieBuilder` class and a `CookieOptions` class, but very little on how to use these.

What i'm looking for is the best practice for adding such structured cookies using .NET 6 or a pointer to some good documentation to read.

##### Disclaimer

I am very new to the whole .NET framework, and don't fully understand the difference between .NET and ASP.NET so there might be that I have misunderstood something here when searching.

Comment: This should help clarify your question about .NET and ASP.NET: [what-is-aspnet](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/aspnet/what-is-aspnet)

Comment: Browsers love cookies, meanwhile API is allergic to them.

Comment: This talks about the `Cookie` Class, which exists in .Net 6 and can be used to construct a `Cookie` : [system.net.cookie](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.cookie?view=net-6.0)